# How to display data correctly in spacing table view cells

Tags: swift, uitableview

Only the first element from the array is displayed in my spacing cells.

I have no problems displaying data in simple cells without spacing, but when I need spacing cells and change my code, only the first item is displayed

```
let test = ["1","2","3"]
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return test.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
    section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    let cellSpacingHeight: CGFloat = 10
    return cellSpacingHeight
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    return headerView
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SellerPlacesCell", for: indexPath) as! SellerPlacesCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    cell.namePlace.text = test[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

[image]
How to fix it?

if in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
    section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
return 1
```

i replace `return 1` to `test.count` have this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
cell.namePlace.text = test[indexPath.row]
```

with

```
cell.namePlace.text = test[indexPath.section]
```

the spacing is for the fact that you display sections , so you need to access the array with `section` not `row`

Comment: spacing occurs between sections and for each section you set rows to 1 so for all of them array index = 0 is the accessed one hence no 2,3